# $_POST error after saving information that was returned via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Have issue with PHP $_POST. Then I save information and check $_POST['g_kcal']; returned

```
Notice: Undefined index: g_kcal in
```

This field g_kcal count's all input fields values after input change. It returns new input with name = 'g_kcal' via ajax.

JavaScript:

```
$('.box-body').change(function(){
    var totalPointsKcal = 0;

    $(this).find('input[name="kcal[]"]').each(function(i,n){
        totalPointsKcal += parseFloat($(n).val(),10); 
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajaxLoader.php',
        data: {
            galutinis_kcal:totalPointsKcal,
        },
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById("galutinis").innerHTML=response;
        }
    });
});
```

ajaxLoader.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['galutinis_kcal'])) {
    $kcal = $_POST['galutinis_kcal'];

    echo "<input class='skaiciuokle kcal1' type='text' name='g_kcal' value=". round($kcal, 1) ." disabled>";
}
```

Can't find their the problem is. Maybe POST can't receive information that was send via ajax ?

Comment: Dont see the place where you check your `$_POST['g_kcal']`

Comment: the place is n file there input field is. Have more fields where I enter values and it return my entered values, but g_kcal  notice as undefined.

Comment: What happens when you execute `$('.kcal1').trigger('change');`? Do you submit the received input?

Comment: it was from my old code, this don't do anything, I remove this.

Comment: I think you should be doing `g_kcal:totalPointsKcal` in your JS OR you should do `$_POST['galutinis_kcal']` in your php

Comment: didn't help this one.

Comment: the bracket's shouldn't be inside `input[name="kcal[]"]` but in the input itself, as in `name='g_kcal[]'` plus the names don't match up here, so your question is unclear.

Comment: *"and check $_POST['g_kcal'];"* - Oh, where's that?

Comment: in page test.php there ajaxLoader.php return input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @Fred-ii- input[name="kcal[]"] then input with name = "kcal[]" change, it count and return other input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was input field was set to DISABLE. Now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Content Type in your Ajax POST:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'ajaxLoader.php',
    data: {
        galutinis_kcal:totalPointsKcal,
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        document.getElementById("galutinis").innerHTML=response;
        $('.kcal1').trigger('change');
    }
});
```

If you don't set the content type of the Ajax call the body (data) won't be sent.

Comment: not working, now the input field disappears and ajax loader not return new field.

Comment: Can you verify that $_POST["galutinis_kcal"] is still not set? You may also need to add `dataType: "text/html"` to your ajax request. `dataType` is the content type that your ajax call expects from the server.

Comment: Without dataType and contentType I receive information and new input with counted value. But with dataType and contentType set it didn't enter success function, I just check with alert();

Answer (score 0):

At the server side use this code to get data sent via AJAX Request:

```
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if(isset($info->galutinis_kcal)){
    $kcal = $info->galutinis_kcal;
    echo "<input class='skaiciuokle kcal1' type='text' name='g_kcal' value=". round($kcal, 1) ." disabled>";
}
```

at the Client side use JSON.stringify before send your request

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'ajaxLoader.php',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        galutinis_kcal:totalPointsKcal
    }),
    success: function (response) {
        document.getElementById("galutinis").innerHTML=response;
    }
});
```

Comment: it returned new input value, but when I save, I still receive Notice: Undefined index:

Comment: The php file returned the value?, where are you saving?

Comment: know I'm in test.php there are ajax request, javascript code. In test.php then input change, the code above count value and send to ajaxLoader.php and it innerHTML the #galutinis. And i see value in input. Then i click button to save. Form method="test.php" return in same page. And then I receive Notice: Undefined index: g_kcal in