# Call an operation in PHP SOAP web service from Android Phonegap

Tags: php, android, cordova, soap

In my PHP web service, I have a function:

```
function create_promo($codeBarre, $designation, $dateDebut, $dateFin, $prix, $TVA)
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phone', 'root', '');
    $req = $db->prepare("insert into promotion 
                           values
                             (:codeBarre, :designation, :dateDebut, :dateFin, :prix, :TVA)");
    $req->execute(array(':codeBarre'=>$codeBarre, ':designation'=>$designation,
                        ':dateDebut'=>date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateDebut)),
                        ':dateFin'=>date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateFin)), 
                        ':prix'=>$prix, ':TVA'=>$TVA));  
    return "promotion créer";    
}
```

This function is under C:\Wamp\WWW.

I create my Cordova project and I write this code :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Ajouter").click(function() {
            var codeBarre = $("#codeBarre").val();
            var designation = $("#designation").val();
            var dateDebut = $("#dateDebut").val();
            var dateFin = $("#dateFin").val();
            var prix = $("#prix").val();
            var TVA = $("#TVA").val();
            var dataString = "codeBarre=" + codeBarre + "&designation=" + designation + "&dateDebut=" + dateDebut + "&dateFin=" + dateFin + "&prix=" + prix + "&TVA=" + TVA + "&Ajouter=";
            $.ajax({
                url:"https://192.168.1.12/testphone/server.php//create_promo",
                type:"POST",
                data:dataString,
                crossDomain:true,
                cache:false,
                beforeSend: function(){ $("#insert").val('Connecting...');},
                success: function(data){
                    if (data=="ok")
                    {
                        alert("inserted");
                        $("#Ajouter").val('submit');
                    }
                    else if (data=="error")
                    {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <!--<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
  <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
  <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>-->
  <form method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Code Barre:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="codeBarre"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Designation:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="designation"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date Debut:</td>
        <td> <input type="date" id="dateDebut"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date fin:</td>
        <td><input type="date" id="dateFin"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prix:</td>
        <td> <input type="number" id="prix" step="any"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TVA:</td>
        <td> <input type="number" id="TVA"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td> <input type="button" id="Ajouter" value="Ajouter"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>        

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

The Cordova project is on the C: directory.
The alert message is not displaying; how I can display the error?

Comment: you're testing the code in the browser?

Comment: No, I test in emulateur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be generated because the script does not load when the device is ready, Try to change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
```

to

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    $("#Ajouter").click(function() {
    //.... rest of code

}
```

add error function to catch if request is failing

```
$.ajax({
            url:"https://192.168.1.12/testphone/server.php//create_promo",
            type:"POST",
            data:dataString,
            crossDomain:true, 
            cache:false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#insert").val('Connecting...');},
            success: function(data){
                if (data=="ok")
                {
                    alert("inserted");
                    $("#Ajouter").val('submit');
                }
                else if (data=="error")
                {
                    alert("error");
                }
            },
            error: function(err){
                 alert('error'+err);
            }
});
```

I also would recommend you change type of your input:

```
<input type="submit" id="Ajouter" value="Ajouter">
```

and change the event of click to submit with prevent default, something like this:

```
$("#Ajouter").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Here is your code working: http://jsfiddle.net/07t069uf/5

Comment: No message is displayed.

Comment: you're SOAP service at create_promo receive a POST or GET request?

Comment: How I can verify the type of request but normaly a POST request.

Comment: are you using some sort of framework for your backend? because in your code I can't see the type of request

Comment: No. Could you  give me an exemple of request maybe this is my fault because I'm beginner with SOAP and Phonegap ?

Comment: I think your approach still isn't SOAP , because I don't see in your PHP code anything related, so if you still don't have code implemented I would recommend you to switch to JSON with RESTFUL API, is easier to communciate with Phonegap (Front-end), if not, here there is a tutorial how to make a SOAP service with PHP http://www.sitepoint.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/ here there is an example how to implement a POST http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578959/post-error-after-saving-information-that-was-returned-via-ajax/36579245#36579245

Comment: Thanks @Jose Rojas

Comment: The code work for me. Just one question this url https://httpbin.org/post contain my php function ? or what ? Because, the new record is not insert into database.

Comment: that's a test server, change the url to your local address. You also change something else in your PHP file something like the question I commented previously